# graphene-django custom get_queryset of DjangoObjectType does not work

Tags: graphene-django

in official docs: https://docs.graphene-python.org/projects/django/en/latest/queries/#default-queryset. In practice nothing happens. Please help. Below, for example i have just simple part of code with model Contact that have 3 fields(id, kind, value). I want the ContactType to always be filtered with kind='PHONE'.

```
class ContactType(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = Contact

    @classmethod
    def get_queryset(cls, queryset, info):
        return queryset.filter(kind='PHONE')

class ContactQuery(graphene.ObjectType):
    contacts = graphene.List(ContactType)

    def resolve_contacts(self, info, **kwargs):
        return Contact.objects.all()
```

The query:

```
{
    contacts {
        id
        kind
        value
    }
}
```

returns:

```
{
  "data": {
    "contacts": [
      {
        "id": "1",
        "kind": "INSTAGRAM",
        "value": "technodomkz"
      },
      {
        "id": "3",
        "kind": "YOUTUBE",
        "value": "UCF-HjvMMvgnhXhO4shk9i9Q"
      },
      {
        "id": "4",
        "kind": "FACEBOOK",
        "value": "technodomkz"
      },
      {
        "id": "5",
        "kind": "TWITTER",
        "value": "technodom_kz"
      },
      {
        "id": "6",
        "kind": "PHONE",
        "value": "88000801111"
      },
      {
        "id": "7",
        "kind": "PHONE",
        "value": "87272799999"
      },
      {
        "id": "8",
        "kind": "EMAIL",
        "value": "callcenter@technodom.kz"
      },
      {
        "id": "2",
        "kind": "WEBSITE",
        "value": "www.technodom.kz"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

instead of:

```
{
  "data": {
    "contacts": [
      {
        "id": "6",
        "kind": "PHONE",
        "value": "88000801111"
      },
      {
        "id": "7",
        "kind": "PHONE",
        "value": "87272799999"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you specify your problem? You could for example add a bit of context and show us your piece of code responsible for this error.

Comment: Thanks @louisfischer for feedback. I updated the question with more info

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking for the answer to this question, it is answered [here](https://github.com/graphql-python/graphene-django/issues/698)

> Try swapping out List for DjangoConnectionField.
>   Looks like we need to document that get_queryset works with the DjangoConnectionField and that non-relay fields like List don't have the same magic.

Comment: DjangoListField works too but without the relay spec:
"DjangoConnectionField acts similarly to DjangoListField but returns a paginated connection following the relay spec"